# Is it possible to execute Databricks Notebooks from a SQL Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, azure-databricks

In the past I have only used Azure Data Factory to run a Databricks Notebook via pipeline activity in a stored procedure.

Can someone let me know if its actually possible to run an Azure Databricks Notebook purely from a stored procedure in Azure SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically it's possible to call the [Databricks Jobs REST API](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/jobs.html) from TSQL in on-prem installations (like [this](https://medium.com/data-bloodies/how-to-call-api-bys-using-tsql-792078da95cc)), but according to the answer on MS site [this is not supported for Azure SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/551444/calling-api-from-auze-sql-stored-procedure.html).

But the first question that should be asked - why do you need this?

Comment: Hi Alex, I didn't answer you're question - ' why we need this'? At present, we're using stored procedures in Data Factory to query a SQL database before triggering/executing a databricks notebook. However, we need to run the stored procedures at 10 sec intervals, and it would be crazy to trigger ADF for every 10 sec's. Therefore, I would like to execute the notebook directly from the database via a stored procedure. Is that possible?

Comment: I think that you need to rethink your architecture… Fir me it looks like a streaming use case, or something like that.

Comment: ok, Alex I hear you.

Comment: It really depends on what you notebooks are doing - how data is ingested, how processed, etc.